# ListView does not refresh when string array model changes

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

My ListView doesnt show new entries in my model when they are added.

When a dialog opens I copy a QStringList from a C++ item into a Qml property.
The user then modifies the array using provided controls (add, modify, remove).

Sadly the ListView doesnt update when I modify the property. The property is modified correctly (as seen by debugging output).

How can I make the ListView updating automatically using data binding?

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var things

    Component.onCompleted: things = [] // normally retrieved from C++ QStringList

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        RowLayout {
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            TextField {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                id: theTextField
            }

            Button {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: qsTr("Append")
                onPressed: {
                    things.push(theTextField.text)
                    console.log(things)
                }
            }

            Button {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: qsTr("Remove")
                onPressed: {
                    var index = things.indexOf(theTextField.text)
                    if(index == -1)
                        console.warn('Not found!')
                    else
                        things.splice(index, 1)
                    console.log(things)
                }
            }

            Button {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: qsTr("Clear");
                onPressed: {
                    things = [];
                    console.log(things)
                }
            }
        }

        ListView {
            id: listView

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: things
            delegate: Label {
                text: modelData
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is, that there is no `thingsChanged`-signal when using a function to modify the `things`. The reference stored in `things` will stay the same, no matter what you do.

For the data models such as `ListModel` this is the same, but there exist [special signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#signals) many of which are used to indicate to any view, that it should update it's content.

If you desperately need to use arrays, you need to call `thingsChanged()` manually, whenever you changed something to the arrays content. But as this indicates only that the whole array has changed, one of the major strengths of a `View` are void - the ability to change only what has been changed.

When a `View` reacts to a `thingsChanged`-signal, it will destroy all current delegates and then recreate them again, no matter whether anything will be different.

If you use a `ListModel` or `QAbstractItemModel`-descendent, the `View` can insert single instances of new delegates, remove or alter them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the array with a real ListModel. Use the function append!

```
Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: qsTr("Clear");
            onPressed: {
                model.append({"data": theTextField.text})
            }
        }
```

and at the and  of the main block 
  ListModel { id :model }